# Spring Integration Global variables

Tags: spring-integration

Here is my question..

I am planning on using aggregator in the spring integration framework.

I want to group messages using an id and send them down the pipeline for further processing, but I also want to group these message on a different set of fields and create a hashmap which will be used by all the messages that I grouped using first criteria, so this hashmap is kind of a global variable.

Example.
Message 1:
Execution id:100
Account id:1234
cusip:IBM
Quantity:10

Message 2:
Execution id:100
Account id:4321
cusip:IBM
Quantity:20

Message 3:
Execution id:200
Account id:1234
cusip:IBM
Quantity:30

Message 4:
Execution id:200
Account id:4321
cusip:IBM
Quantity:40

I want to maintain a global hashmap, by adding quantity for each Account id and cusip
Key        Value
1234, IBM->40
4321, IBM->60
and aggregate these 4 messages based on execution id and send 2 messages down the pipeline.

I hope I am not giving too many details and causing confusion.

I have two questions.
1. How to maintain that global hashmap and use it for the message further down the pipeline?
2. Is aggregator the right choice for this sort of problem?

Looking forward to your repsponse!

Thanks!
Supriya

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want the global hashmap for but, yes, you can aggregate on multiple fields, just use an appropriate `correlation-expression` (or use a custom `CorrelationStrategy` if it's too complex for an expression).

You can create a `<bean/>`, e.g. a `ConcurrentHashMap` and reference it from your beans, or even use expressions to add to it.